# Одновременное применение двух фильтров

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть два фильтра listBox в одном objectManager.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно их одновременно применять. Трудности возникают с пониманием как правильно использовать filterMonitor
при двух фильтрах

```js
var listBoxItems1 = ['Ок', 'Не ок']
  .map(function(title) {
    return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
      data: {
        content: title
      },
      state: {
        selected: true
      }
    })
  }),
  listBoxControl1 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
    data: {
      content: 'По статусам',
      title: 'Фильтр'
    },
    items: listBoxItems1,
    state: {
      expanded: false,
      filters: listBoxItems1.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
        filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
        return filters;
      }, {})
    }
  });
myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl1);

// Добавим отслеживание изменения признака, выбран ли пункт списка.
listBoxControl1.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
  var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
  var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl1.state.get('filters'));
  filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
  listBoxControl1.state.set('filters', filters);
});
var listBoxItems2 = ['a', 'b']
  .map(function(title) {
    return new ymaps.control.ListBoxItem({
      data: {
        content: title
      },
      state: {
        selected: false
      }
    })
  }),
  listBoxControl2 = new ymaps.control.ListBox({
    data: {
      content: 'По тегам',
      title: 'Фильтр'
    },
    items: listBoxItems2,
    state: {
      expanded: false,
      filters: listBoxItems2.reduce(function(filters, filter) {
        filters[filter.data.get('content')] = filter.isSelected();
        return filters;
      }, {})
    }
  });
myMap.controls.add(listBoxControl2);

listBoxControl2.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
  var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
  var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, listBoxControl2.state.get('filters'));
  filters[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
  listBoxControl2.state.set('filters', filters);
});

//Вот тут вопросы как правильно применить оба listBoxControl при разных getFilterFunction
var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl1.state);
filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
  // Применим первый фильтр.
  objectManager1.setFilter(getFilterFunction1(filters));
});
var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(listBoxControl2.state);
filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
  // Применим второй фильтр.
  objectManager1.setFilter(getFilterFunction2(filters));
});


function getFilterFunction1(categories){
    return function(obj){
        var status = obj.properties.balloonContent;
        return categories[status]
    }
}
function getFilterFunction2(categories){
    return function(obj){
        var status = obj.properties.balloonContentHeader;
        return categories[status]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Достаточно написать две функции фильтрации и объединить их:

```
listBoxControl.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
    var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
    var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, myMap.controls.state.filters);
    filters.first[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
    myMap.controls.state.set('filters', filters);
});
listBoxControl2.events.add(['select', 'deselect'], function(e) {
    var listBoxItem = e.get('target');
    var filters = ymaps.util.extend({}, myMap.controls.state.filters);
    filters.second[listBoxItem.data.get('content')] = listBoxItem.isSelected();
    myMap.controls.state.set('filters', filters);
});

var filterMonitor = new ymaps.Monitor(myMap.controls.state);
filterMonitor.add('filters', function(filters) {
    objectManager.setFilter(getFilterFunction(filters));
});

function getFilterFunction(categories){
    return function(obj){
    console.log(obj)
        return categories.second[obj.properties.type] && categories.first[obj.properties.balloonContent]
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/npmgv8d4/